# Can I upload TeamCity definitions as XML?

Tags: teamcity

TeamCity appears to store the definitions for builds, projects, templates etc as XML internally.

This is exposed in the "Administration > Audit" view where you can see diffs that people made to individual configurations, at URLs like `http://teamcityserver/admin/settingsDiffView.html?id=project:project10&versionBefore=8&versionAfter=9&actionId=3151`

I'd like to manage a TeamCity setup partially from outside the web interface - e.g. for example keep the build definitions in version control and perhaps programmatically generate them.

Is there any way I can directly upload definitions in this format (or any similar alternative)? I'm aware that there are various APIs and extension points to TeamCity but haven't managed to find any that gives direct access to anything like this.

I can live with the format changing with TeamCity versions if necessary - it would be a reasonable price to pay for the other benefits.

Comment: There's an open TC feature request for something along these lines: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-2806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamCity 9 adds a new ["Versioned Settings"](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Storing+Project+Settings+in+Version+Control) feature which keeps these XML files under version control and allows changes to be made via the VCS.

In TeamCity 9.0 this can be git or mercurial, and the upcoming TeamCity 9.1 will add support for [Perforce](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-38492) and [Subversion](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-40065#tab=History).

I've been using it with git for a few months and it works quite nicely in practice.

I sometimes have trouble persuading TeamCity to notice changes coming in from the VCS - particularly when deleting projects - but otherwise it's been really useful for standardising configuration and spinning up new job chains quickly.

Another slight annoyance is that you can't configure the location within the repository that the settings come from - it's always `.teamcity` in the root - so I've had to use multiple branches or repositories to manage multiple TeamCity servers.

Answer (score 3):

### For TeamCity 9.x and newer

As reported by Ganesh in the comments to this answer, an option was added in 9.x that supports changes and versioning through Source Code Management (SCM) tools. Please see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29486305/734790) for 9.x and beyond.

### For TeamCity 8.x and older

It might not be the "approved" way, but you can edit the project files on disk, and those changes will appear in your build configs. *I have successfully edited them outside of the Web UI after they were created.*

So, you could probably open that folder up as a restricted network share or set up ssh.

You'll find it at `$TeamCityData/config/projects/` and then they are stored in subfolders such as `$projectName/buildTypes/$buildFile.xml`

An example is:
`E:\TeamCityData\config\projects\CSandbox\buildTypes\CSandbox_Project1TrunkBuildUnitTest.xml`

Comment: That's very useful, thanks. I tried it and it also seems to work for me.

One difficulty is that the Audit view of the job isn't aware of the change. This is not surprising as there is no active notification of the change to TeamCity. I worry that going behind the back of TeamCity like this might cause other more important things to miss changes as well.

Comment: I have been using it to override something that the UI does not expose. My finding has been that it picks up the change in the XML and behaves properly when I (or a commit) trigger the build. However, if I go to the screen that has these options on it and do not hit cancel, it overwrites my change. That's why this might not be the approved way. I would recommend setting up a sandbox project under your root, then copy your build script there and test it out.

Comment: If you modify the file directly, you'll most likely have to restart TeamCity in order to have it not overwrite your changes when you go through the Web UI to edit them.

Comment: This answer is still right for TeamCity 8.x and before, but as TeamCity 9 has since come out with a much better way of doing that I'm switching the accepted answer. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: No problem and thanks for mentioning that. I'll edit the post to say for TC 8.x and previous